# SQLite3: Insert BLOB with NULL characters in C++

Tags: sqlite, null, escaping, blob

I'm working on the development of a C++ API which uses custom-designed plugins 
to interface with different database engines using their APIs and specific SQL 
syntax.

Currently, I'm attempting to find a way of inserting BLOBs, but since `NULL` is 
the terminating character in C/C++, the BLOB becomes truncated when constructing
the *INSERT INTO* query string. So far, I've worked with

```
//...
char* sql;
void* blob;
int len;
//...
blob = some_blob_already_in_memory;
len = length_of_blob_already_known;
sql = sqlite3_malloc(2*len+1);
sql = sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%Q)", (char*)blob);
//...
```

I expect that, if it is at all possible to do it in the SQLite3 interactive console, it should be possible to construct the query string with properly escaped `NULL` characters. Maybe there's a way to do this with standard SQL which is also supported by SQLite SQL syntax?

Surely someone must have faced the same situation before. I've googled and found some answers but were in other programming languages (Python).

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: [This](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) page seems to list all the functions you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to use this function with a prepared statement.

```
int sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const void*, int n, void(*)(void*));
```

In C/C++, the standard way of dealing with NULLs in strings is to either store the beginning of the string and a length, or store a pointer to the beginning of a string and one to the end of the string.

Answer (score 10):

Thank you all again for your feedback. This time I'm reporting how I solved the problem with the help of the indications provided here. Hopefully this will help others in the future.

As suggested by the first three posters, I did use prepared statements — additionally because I was also interested in getting the columns' data types, and a simple `sqlite3_get_table()` wouldn't do.

After preparing the SQL statement in the form of the following constant string:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(?,?,?,?);
```

it remains the *binding* of the corresponding values. This is done by issuing as many `sqlite3_bind_blob()` calls as the columns. (I also resorted to `sqlite3_bind_text()` for other "simple" data types because the API I'm working on can translate integers/doubles/etc into a string). So:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
/* ... */
void* blobvalue[4] = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
int blobsize[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
const char* tail = NULL;
const char* sql = "INSERT INTO tabl VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
sqlite3_stmt* stmt = NULL;
sqlite3* db = NULL;
/* ... */
sqlite3_open("sqlite.db", &db);
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,
                   sql, strlen(sql) + 1,
                   &stmt, &tail);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 
                      i + 1, blobvalue[i], blobsize[i], 
                      SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
}
if(sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
    printf("Error message: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_close(db);
```

Note also that some functions (`sqlite3_open_v2()`, `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`) appear on the later SQLite versions (I suppose 3.5.x and later).

The SQLite table `tabl` in file `sqlite.db` can be created with (for example)

```
CREATE TABLE tabl(a TEXT PRIMARY KEY, b TEXT, c TEXT, d TEXT);
```

Comment: @kibab Thanks, fixed it. (BTW, you would have been welcome to have improved it yourself.)

Comment: I didn't know that I can edit others posts :) Thanks, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You want to precompile the statement `sqlite_prepare_v2()`, and then bind the blob in using `sqlite3_bind_blob()`. Note that the statement you bind in will be *INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)*.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but does having a single "?" placemarker works? Or is it necessary to have as many as the number of table fields?

Comment: Yes, you will need to match the field count if you do it this way.